# Add an echo into long one liner

Tags: bash

I have a long line:

```
for host in $(for owner in $(t-lock --summary | grep -i scheduled | awk '{ print $4 }' | sort -u); do t-nuke --stale --owner $owner --unlock --dry-run 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -e 'foo\|blah' | cut -d ':' -f1; done); do t-updatekeys $host; t-update-inventory $host; done
```

I don't seem to be able to add "echo $host" and "echo $owner" inside of ()

Thanks for your help!

Comment: maybe time to split this one liner into  clean script?

Comment: @OzOg maybe, but I really want to understand what's wrong with this :)

Comment: "I don't seem to be able to add" doesn't explain what is the problem. I cannot tell what is your difficulty, your goal, and what is the question here.

Comment: Post the command that's not working, not the command that works. We can't tell what you're doing wrong when you just describe it in words.

Comment: Note that when you do an echo to stdout inside a command substitution, that content is *read as output to the command substitution*, not written to the console.

Comment: Also, in general, [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) -- the practice leads to buggy, fragile code.

Comment: (You might also consider fixing the bugs that http://shellcheck.net/ identifies).

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy to read, so it's no wonder you're having trouble finding where to put the `echo` calls. Without a doubt, you should split the lines.

That said, try this:

```
for host in $(for owner in $(t-lock --summary | grep -i scheduled | awk '{ print $4 }' | sort -u); do echo $owner; t-nuke --stale --owner $owner --unlock --dry-run 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -e 'foo\|blah' | cut -d ':' -f1; done); do echo $host; t-updatekeys $host; t-update-inventory $host; done
```

Comment: tried that and it did multiform vars for following commands and breaks, that's why was asking.  thx !

Comment: maybe you're all right I should stop this madness !  but why it wont' work ?

Comment: Having very long bash one-liners _does_ work. There's nothing technically wrong with it, Bash will run a script the same way with one line or many. The issue comes with human readability. Especially when submitting to a site like Stack Overflow, you want to make sure your program or script is _as human-readable as possible_ to allow the other humans on this site to help. With one-liners, it's physically difficult to see where one loop ends and another begins, where one subshell ends, etc. Breaking it out into an easily human-readable script will help enormously with your scripting effort.